# monetdb failed to bulk load 42000 syntax error

Tags: monetdb

I'm trying to bulk load some data into monetdb.
I followed [this example](http://dev.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB/file/tip/java/example/SQLcopyinto.java).
It works for my test data. But when I use the data from production environment, I get exceptions.

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: 42000!syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting DELIMITERS in: "copy into dm.fact_sem_keyword_collection from stdin using delimters"
25005!current transaction is aborted (please ROLLBACK)
at com.lietou.bi.dw.task.common.dataexchange.MonetDBBulkLoadWriter.flush(MonetDBBulkLoadWriter.java:140)
... 12 more
```

and I found the following log from the debug log.

```
20150804x_m_0001323100000001255480000000001310100152015-08-05 10:28:44
20150804x_z_0002000000000001000000000000000002015-08-05 10:28:44
20150804xn_cd_01000000000002000000000000000002015-08-05 10:28:44
20150804z_s_0002000000000001000000000000000002015-08-05 10:28:44

RD 1438779576672: read final block: 190 bytes
RX 1438779576672: !42000!syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting DELIMITERS in: "copy into dm.fact_sem_keyword_collection from stdin using delimters"
!25005!current transaction is aborted (please ROLLBACK)

RD 1438779576672: inserting prompt
```

I think there must be some bad data, but I don't know how to find more details to help me locate it.

And there is one more thing. Monetdb seems to read data using a buffer size of 8190 bytes. But right before the exception, there is a `write final block` of different size. Logs are showed below. What does this mean?

```
...
TD 1438779576129: write block: 8190 bytes
TX 1438779576129:
... 
TD 1438779576137: write block: 8190 bytes
TX 1438779576137:
...
TD 1438779576137: write final block: 5921 bytes
TX 1438779576137:
...
```

Comment: I tried to use jdbc batch execution and it just worked. There might be a bug in monetdb bulk load.

Comment: Looks like an incomplete COPY INTO statement to me.

Comment: To my untrained eyes, this seems to be caused by a typo: `delimiters` instead of `delimters` at the end of the query